# Storing particular brackets (opening, closing) in a stack using lists containing brackets

Tags: java, list, stack

```
    static List<String> openingBrackets = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> closingBrackets = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static final String quit = ""; // to be used in sentinel loop

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // list containing all the opening brackets
        openingBrackets.add("(");
        openingBrackets.add("{");
        openingBrackets.add("[");
        openingBrackets.add("<");
        System.out.println(openingBrackets);

        // list that contains the closing brackets
        closingBrackets.add(")");
        closingBrackets.add("}");
        closingBrackets.add("]");
        closingBrackets.add(">");
        System.out.println(closingBrackets);

        String sent = "value"; // some dummy value assigned to sent.

        // creating a stack to store the opening brackets
        Stack stackOpening = new Stack();

        // creating a stack to store the closing brackets
        Stack stackClosing = new Stack(); 

        while (!sent.equals(quit))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a string to test:");
            sent = scanner.nextLine();

            for (int i=0; i<sent.length(); i++)
            {
                char c = sent.charAt(i);

                if (! openingBrackets.contains(c))
                {
                    // push the opening brackets in the String sent 
                    // in the Stack for opening brackets

                    stackOpening.push(c); 
                }

                if (! closingBrackets.contains(c))
                {
                    // push only the closing brackets in the String
                    // in the stack for closing brackets

                    stackClosing.push(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Sample input:**

- `(< [ { } ( { > ) ] >`

> **Sample output:**

- Stack (for opening brackets): `[ (, <, [, {, }, (, { ]`
- Stack (for closing brackets): `[ >, ), ], > ]`

> **However, when printing the two stacks separately; it output**s

- `[ (, <, [, {, }, (, {, >, ), ], > ]` for both stacks

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please see this [THREAD](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: How do you print your stacks, besides, try using if-else and remove "!" punctuation from if conditions.

Comment: Using normal 'print' statement; System.out.println(".." + stackOpening);
I removed the "!", but it didn't store anything in the stack.

Comment: Is this `Stack` the class from the Java standard library? `java.util.Stack`? What are the definitions of `openingBrackets` and `closingBrackets`?

Comment: List<String> openingBrackets = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> closingBrackets = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 0):

`openingBrackets` and `closingBrackets` are [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)s of `String`s. However you check, if these collections contain [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)s:

```
char c = sent.charAt(i);

if (! openingBrackets.contains(c))
```

Since the `Collection`s don't contain any `Character`s, no matches are found, which is why all elements are added to both `Stack`s.

To fix this, either make `openingBrackets` and `closingBrackets` `Collection`s of `Character`s or convert `c` to a `String` before testing, if it's contained in one of those `Collection`s.

(Most `Collection`s check, if they contain a element by using the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method, which for `String` and `Character` only returns `true`, if both instances are of the same type)

Comment: Worked when I changed the Collections of openingBrackets and closingBrackets to 'Character'. Thank you. :)